# Trouble Embedding Google Trends Chart in Local HTML File

Tags: html, css, dashboard, google-trends

I'm trying to create a local dashboard with embedded google trends charts on various topics. When I create a standard HTML file and paste the code snippet from Google Trends, the chart goes full-width but cuts off at around 300px or so: [Original Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmN0R.png)

I looked around and tried an iframe solution (as people have suggested in other posts here) but I'm having trouble implementing it. I'm pretty new to using iframes and advanced elements/tags.

Here's a link to the code I customized based on other examples I've seen on here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w6Dnyk0h4ktJ7KaRz-yrpqVhlHmhWVp-/view?usp=sharing

Here's what the rendered code looks like when I open the file locally in my browser:
[Unexpected Results from Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f96lB.png)

This might be a stupid question, but even so, I'd love to get some help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code snippet below, I tried to solve the problem that you are having in paragraph one, Hope this solution works for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.myDiv {
  border: 1px outset lightblue;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Data Tracking</h1>
  
        <h2>COVID-19 Data</h2>
        
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/2431_RC04/embed_loader.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("TIMESERIES", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"/m/03376x","geo":"GB","time":"today 5-y"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {"exploreQuery":"date=today%205-y&geo=GB&q=%2Fm%2F03376x","guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"}); 

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].addEventListener( "load", function(e) {
    this.setAttribute('height','450px')
} );
</script>

            
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank for providing answer to above issue. I had similar issue. Currently, my html looks like  this. I was wondering how to adjust the height ? I had to select width because  if I use height then entire container covers the page. src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/3349_RC01/embed_loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">trends.embed.renderWidget("dailytrends", "",{"geo":"AR","guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"});</script>
    document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].addEventListener("load", function(e) {
      this.setAttribute('width', '350px');

Comment: Hi @biggboss2019, I am not able to get you, could you please explain how you want to see it

Comment: If you want to adjust it in specific dimensions you can use like this:
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].addEventListener( "load", function(e) {
    this.setAttribute('height','450px');
 this.setAttribute('width','450px');
} );
</script>